# I am not able to download any plugin for audio or video on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, 13.10, video, rhythmbox, plugins

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10. And for some reason I am unable to download any plugin automatically. I never had this problem before. Here is an image what Rhythmbox or the default video player says while downloading plugins. Any help will be appreciated.

[screenshot](http://s17.postimg.org/714355j0v/Screenshot_from_2013_12_05_21_03_04.png)

Comment: We can no longer see the image because of the broken link :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you have not installed any codec for playing them.

For solving that, just install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` using the terminal. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal and run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

You can also do the same by searching for `ubuntu-restricted-extras` on Ubuntu Software Center and install it.

`ubuntu-restricted-extras` is a meta-package and other dependencies, like `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`, `gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3`, `gstreamer0.10-pitfdll`, `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`, `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly`, `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse`, `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse`, `icedtea6-plugin`, `libavcodec-extra-52`, `libmp4v2-0`, `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, `unrar`, are useful too.

Comment: okay. Ill try that now. Was this required on previous releases as well? Coz i don't remember doing this before.

Comment: it doesnt comes pre-installed due to some reasons , you have to have to install it after installing Ubuntu , or at the time of installation you need to mark install third party plugins after connecting to internet, then every plug in and codecs would be downloaded it self. Install restricted extras if it solves your problem kindly accept this answer as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Installing  ubuntu-restricted-extras package will solve your problem.
Run 'sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras' to install the package.

Comment: yes bro, i know ultimately that is the final solution. But i just dont understand why isnt it able to find any plugin on its own. I am using ubuntu since 10.04 but this never happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the settings in update manager
ubuntu software tab-in downloadable from the intenet tick all sever pages then change download from tab to main server.then go to terminal type

- sudo apt-get update

  then go and select any movie and try to play it will ask for some of packages need to download click download yyou can now able to view audio and video in your system

Comment: I tried that. Din't work. Tried it on Main server as well as server for India. And all the checkboxes are already ticked.